# Does inequality on arithmetic genera hold for all normal models of curves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Let $f : X \to \mathrm{Spec}(R)$ be a model of a curve. Explicitly, f is flat, proper of relative dimension 1, and R is a dvr with fraction field K and residue field k of characteristic p. Furthermore, assume that $X_K$ is geometrically integral and X is normal. Let $X_j$ be the (reduced) irreducible components of X_k. These are integral schemes and hence have $k_j = H^0(X_j, \mathcal{O}_{X_j})$ a finite field extension of $k$. Denote by $m_j$ the geometric multiplicity of $X_j$.

The question is: does the following inequality hold:

$(*) \quad \sum_j \dim_{k_j} H^1(X_j, \mathcal{O}_{X_j}) \le \dim_K H^1(X_K, \mathcal{O}_{X_K})$

Some cases where I know this is true:

(1) if $X$ is regular, intersection theory should give $(*)$

(2) if p does not divide some $m_j$ then Raynaud proves that $f$ is cohomologically flat in dimension 0. This plus constancy of the Euler characteristic allows us to conclude a stronger version of $(*)$ with each term multiplied by $[k_j : k]$.

(3) if each $X_j$ is normal then passing to a desingularization $X' \to X$ there is a component of $X'_k$ which maps isomorphically to $X_j$ and hence we reduce to the regular case. Usually, the preimage of $X_j$ could normalize $X_j$ and thus the genus would go down.

(4) if $H^0(X_k, \mathcal{O}_{X_k})$ is reduced then it is a field $k'$ finite over $k$ and each $k_j$ contains $k'$. The constancy of the Euler characteristic then allows us to conclude a stronger version of $(*)$ with each term multiplied by $[k_j : k]$.

Also, $(*)$ is the best inequality we could hope for in this generality.

Indeed, the stronger inequality in (2) is false in general even for $X$ regular. For example, Raynaud in 9.4.3(b) of Spécialisation du foncteur de Picard gives an example where $[k_j : k] = p$ but both $X_K$ and $X_k$ are integral and of arithmetic genus 1.

Likewise, we cannot put the $m_j$ in the formula as one might expect because of examples of a genus 1 curve degenerating to a genus 1 curve with multiplicity.

Comment: As Raynaud proved in [this paper](http://www.numdam.org/item/?id=PMIHES_1970__38__27_0), the condition $H^0(X_s,\mathcal{O}_{X_s})=\kappa$ is satisfied if $\mathrm{char}(\kappa)$ does not divide the gcd of the total multiplicities of the components of $X_s$. In particular it is true if $\kappa$ has characteristic zero.

Comment: @LaurentMoret-Bailly thank you for the reference. In the case that p does divide the gcd of the multiplicities I see that Raynaud provides a counterexample to cohomological flatness. Unless I misunderstand, it satisfies (S) however. Do you know if there is a counterexample in this case?

Comment: If $X$ is normal, then it is $S2$.  In that case, the Cartier divisor $X_s$ is $S1$.  Thus, if it is generically reduced, then it is everywhere reduced.  Is your field $\kappa$ a perfect field?  In that case, reduced is the same as geometrically reduced.

Comment: @JasonStarr I agree in the case of a perfect field. However, I still don't know the answer when $\kappa$ is nonperfect. I would like the result to be true when $\kappa$ is the fraction field of a variety over $\mathbb{F}_p$.